# Distribution of objects into boxes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I had been facing problems with questions on distribution of objects into boxes lately. I thought that it would be a nice idea to frame a general question that covers all cases. It would also help other users on this site as well including me. I would greatly appreciate any help i get.

**Question**: In how many ways can $a$ objects be distributed into $b$ boxes taking into account all the possibilities (distinct and non-distinct) for both the objects and the boxes. ($a$ may be greater than $b$ or may be less than $b$)

There are 8 cases possible.

**When a < b**

**CASE 1**: All the objects are distinct and all the boxes are distinct

**CASE 2**: All the objects are distinct and all the boxes are non-distinct

**CASE 3**: All the objects are non-distinct and all the boxes are distinct

**CASE 4**: All the objects are non-distinct and the boxes are non-distinct

**When a > b**

**CASE 1**: All the objects are distinct and all the boxes are distinct

**CASE 2**: All the objects are distinct and all the boxes are non-distinct

**CASE 3**: All the objects are non-distinct and all the boxes are distinct

**CASE 4**: All the objects are non-distinct and the boxes are non-distinct

What would be the best way to proceed in each case? What does it mean when we say that all the boxes are distinct?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way